# Google Load Balancer map url containing has '#'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have a website configured using GCP load-balancer and GCP storage as backend service.

What is now :

```
https://example.com/#/  --> works
https://example.com/#/path --> works
```

what I want:

https://example.com/#/  but in backend it should hit /#/path.

I have tried with GCP path mapping using `host and path rules` but symbol `#` is causing problem. It converts `#` to `%23` in the broswer and says `key not found`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a URL/URI, the symbol hash (#) has a special meaning and it is a reserved character used as a generic delimiter [1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2), as a forward slash (/) or at (@) does.
Actually the hash symbol is interpreted as an anchor in the URL, so it is expected to point to an anchored part in your document. An example would be:

```
http://example.com/your_page.html#my_document
```

It will link the URL directly at the `my_document` anchor in the `your_page.html`.

So, if you use the hash character differently than this, the URL map will be encoded for security reasons. As stated in the RFC1738 [2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738): The character "#" is unsafe and should always be encoded because it is used in World Wide Web and in other systems to delimit a URL from a fragment/anchor identifier that might follow it.

Due to that, your URL string is being encoded by the browser mechanism.
More information here [3](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP).

Despite it being possible to set an URL mapping using a hash symbol, it is not recommended to do it. So, I kindly encourage you to not use a hash symbol in the URL map.

The reason for it is working as you mention is simply because the hash symbol “#” has been ignored by your web application when it has not been encoded.
So it can works as for `/#/path` or `/#/#/#/path`. But in truth it is interpreting just the `/path`.